# Is there a way to restate linguistic examples in linguex?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, linguistics, linguex

In the [gb4e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) package you can restate an example with the same number using `\exr` instead of `\ex` Does something like this exist for [linguex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/linguex), which claims to be for lazy people?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do this which works roughly in the same way as the corresponding `gb4e` functionality.  We define an `\exr` macro (no trailing `.`) which takes a label as its argument and uses the reference to that label as the example number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@repeated\@repeatedfalse
\newcounter{savedExNo}
\renewcommand{\NormalEx}{\ifExWarning 
     \PackageWarning{linguex}{Check example numbering (screwed up?), 
     check number of empty lines at end of examples.  
     Detected}\fi\ExWarningtrue
     \if@repeated
        \Exformat[\ref{\tmp@ref}]
        \setcounter{ExNo}{\value{savedExNo}}
        \global\@repeatedfalse
     \else
     \if@noftnote\refstepcounter{ExNo}%
        \Exformat[\ExLBr\Exarabic{ExNo}\ExRBr]%
     \else
         \refstepcounter{FnExNo}\Exformat[\FnExLBr\Exroman{FnExNo}\FnExRBr]%
     \fi
     \fi}
\newcommand{\exr}[1]{%
\@repeatedtrue
\setcounter{savedExNo}{\value{ExNo}}
\def\tmp@ref{#1}
\ex.}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ex. This is an example.

\ex. This example will be repeated.\label{r1}

\ex.  \label{r2}
\a. An subexample.
\b. Another subexample.

\ex. Another example.

\exr{r1} This is the first repeated example.

\exr{r2}
\a. A repeated subexample.
\b. Another subexample.

\ex. Another example showing that the numbering continues correctly.

\ex. Another one.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

What about reset the counter?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\def\exr{\setcounter{ExNo}{0}\ex}
\begin{document} 
\ex.  Some text\par 
\ex.  Some text\par 
\exr. Some text\par 
\ex.  Some text\par 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what the corresponding `\exr` command does in `gb4e`. That command takes a label as its argument and uses the number of the `\ref` to that label as the example number.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the simple `\label`-`\ref` system combined with the optional example label (`\ex.[]`). `\label` right after the dot, and `\ref` in square brackets. Here also illustrated for sub-examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document} 
\ex.  Some text

\ex.  Some text

\ex.\label{ex:aa}  Some text (example number to be remembered: \ref{ex:aa})

\ex.  Some text
\a. sub-ex
\b.\label{ex:cc} sub-ex (a sub-example number to be remembered: \ref{ex:cc})

\ex.  Some text

\ex.[\ref{ex:aa}]  Some text (repeated example number: \ref{ex:aa})

\ex.  Some text

\ex.[\ref{ex:cc}]  Some text (with the remembered sub-example number: \ref{ex:cc})

\end{document}
```

[image]