# Print example with same number as previous example, but new sub-number in linguex

Tags: numbering, linguistics, linguex

How do I get the following output using `linguex`:

```
(2) a. James sang to himself
    b. James didn't sing to himself.

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

(2) c. James would not sing to himself
```

I want to write an example with the same numbering as before the text, but with the new sub-numbering scheme.

Comment: Please don't just show the desired output when you ask a question. Instead give a minimal compilable document using the relevant package (in this case `linguex`) showing the output you can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a duplicate of [Is there a way to restate linguistic examples in linguex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310689/2693) but with the added complication of the resumed sublabel number. There's no simple way to do this other than supplying the sublabel manually, as in the the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@repeated\@repeatedfalse
\newcounter{savedExNo}
\renewcommand{\NormalEx}{\ifExWarning 
     \PackageWarning{linguex}{Check example numbering (screwed up?), 
     check number of empty lines at end of examples.  
     Detected}\fi\ExWarningtrue
     \if@repeated
        \Exformat[\ref{\tmp@ref}]
        \setcounter{ExNo}{\value{savedExNo}}
        \global\@repeatedfalse
     \else
     \if@noftnote\refstepcounter{ExNo}%
        \Exformat[\ExLBr\Exarabic{ExNo}\ExRBr]%
     \else
         \refstepcounter{FnExNo}\Exformat[\FnExLBr\Exroman{FnExNo}\FnExRBr]%
     \fi
     \fi}
\newcommand{\exr}[1]{%
\@repeatedtrue
\setcounter{savedExNo}{\value{ExNo}}
\def\tmp@ref{#1}
\ex.}



\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ex. This is an example.

\ex. This example will be repeated.\label{r1}

\ex.  \label{r2}
\a. An subexample.
\b. Another subexample.

\ex. Another example.

\exr{r1} This is the first repeated example.

\exr{r2}
\a.[c.] A repeated subexample.
\b.[d.] Another subexample.

\ex. Another example showing that the numbering continues correctly.

\ex. Another one.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]